# Recorre CSV eliminar linea y guardar usando php

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

Hola tengo una duda que no logró resolver resulta que estoy tratando de recorrer un `CSV`  luego eliminar la linea que yo escoja y finalmente guardar el resto en el mismo `CSV` el código que tengo no esta terminado .

Ejemplo del contenido de datos.vsv

```
 Goggle.com,2019/03/25,2019/04/25,30
Facebook. Com,2019/03/25,2019/04/25,30
Vk.com,2019/03/25,2019/04/25,30
Vídeos.com,2019/03/25,2019/04/25,30
Yahoo.com,2019/03/25,2019/04/25,30
Twitte.com,2019/03/25,2019/04/25,30
```

La variable $restante es aleatoria por lo que puede ser cualquier linea

```
$restante= 0;

$handle = fopen("datos.csv", "r");
        while ($linea = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) {
            $enlace = @$linea[0];
            $fecha1 = @$linea[1];
            $fecha2 = @$linea[2];
            $restante = @$linea[3];



            if($restante == 2){
                //
            }elseif($restante == 0){
                //elimina el enlace 
            $linea[0] = null;
            $linea[1] = null;
            $linea[2] = null;
            $linea[3] = null;

            fputcsv($handle, array($linea[0], $linea[1], $linea[2], $linea[3]));

            }

            $linea[3] =  $restante;


        }
        fclose($handle);
```

Como pueden ver el código no esta terminado por que no encuentro la manera de eliminar la linea y guardar el resto.

Actualización

```
$handle = fopen("datos.csv", "w");
    while ($linea = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) {
        $enlace = @$linea[0];
        $fecha1 = @$linea[1];
        $fecha2 = @$linea[2];
        $restante = @$linea[3];

        $restan = 0;

        if($restan != 0){
        echo " no se borro ninguna linea";
        fputcsv($handle, array($enlace,$fecha1,$fecha2,$restan));
        }else{

       echo "linea borrada: " .$enlace;
        }

    }
    fclose($handle);
```

Con este forma no me da ningún mensaje  y el `datos.csv` lo deja vació

El resultado que espero es que la linea que sea igual a $restante sea borrada de datos.csv

Espero me podáis dar alguna idea. 
Saludes cordiales.

Comment: podrias inclui un ejemplo minimo de tu archivo y el resultado que deseas?

Comment: Lo que busco es leer el datos.csv si la linea coincide con la variable $restante procede a eliminar la linea y guarda solo las demás . igual voy a actualizar la pregunta para ser mas claro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**puedes hacerlo asi:**
en tu caso no es necesario utilizar `fgetcsv` ya que deseas eliminar la linea completa no acceder a los elementos como tal.

> **nota:** la lineas empiezan en `0` ya que es una costumbre para mi que todo empieze en `0`, puedes eliminar el `-1` si deseas que empieze en `1`.

```
<?php 

function remove_line($file,$n){
    //leemos el archivo 
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    // almacenara la data
    $result = "";
    // contador de lineas
    $i =0;
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            // aumentamos en 1 la linea
            $i++;
            // removemos espacios de mas
            $line = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $line));
            // validamos que sea una linea en blanco o el numero de linea especificado y saltamos a la siguiente interacion
            if ( $line == "" || $n == ($i -1)) continue;

            // almacenamos los resultados
            $result .= $line."\n";  
        }
        // cerramos el archivo
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
      die("ups! no se pudo abrir el arcivo {$file};");
    }

    // re abrimos en modo escritura
    $handle = fopen($file, "w+");
    // escribimos la nueva data
    fwrite($handle, $result);
    // cerramos el archivo
    fclose($handle);
}

remove_line("file.csv",2);

?>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta . se me presenta una duda tu usas un .txt me pregunto si igual funciona con un csv . para realizarlo

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions es indistinto la diferencia entre csv, txt, json etc. es solo el formato de extension que no cambia el header del mismo ya que sige siendo texto plano por debajo!

Comment: Bueno gracias le pondré mente